# htaccess force SSL breaks other rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I am trying to force SSL and also redirrect everybody from WWW to Non-WWW (as its a subdomain), but I also have there other rules, for nice URLs... If I delete the code that forces the SSL, it works. If its there, then my nice urls do not work (clicking on news just opens news.php etc.).

**Working** .htaccess (no force SSL):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.sub\.domain\.sk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://sub.domain.sk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^news$ /news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L]
....
....
```

This does **not work**:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.sub\.domain\.sk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://sub.domain.sk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 # If I delete this, I got infinite redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^news$ /news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L]
....
....
```

I also tried this (**not working**):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.sub\.domain\.sk)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^news$ /news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L]
....
....
```

Thanks for help.

Ps.: I found this: [.htaccess https breaks rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872743/htaccess-https-breaks-rewrite-rules) But they never resolved it, as they moved to chat.... Meh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg. Every time I ask some qeuestion, I find answer by trying some more things within couple minutes...

Anyway, this code works for me:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://sub.domain.sk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^news$ /news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L]
```

Comment: That doesn't remove `www`.